# Unable to create unique index with sparse mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I'm using mongodb 2.6.1. However, I'm not able to create unique index with sparse. Currently, I have the following indexes:

```
> db.products.getIndexes()
[
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "_id" : 1
        },
        "name" : "_id_",
        "ns" : "snapyshop_production.products"
    },
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "pickup_location" : "2dsphere"
        },
        "name" : "pickup_location_2dsphere",
        "background" : true,
        "ns" : "snapyshop_production.products",
        "2dsphereIndexVersion" : 2
    },
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "category_id" : 1
        },
        "name" : "category_id_1",
        "background" : true,
        "ns" : "snapyshop_production.products"
    },
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "_keywords" : 1
        },
        "name" : "_keywords_1",
        "background" : true,
        "ns" : "snapyshop_production.products"
    }
]
```

But when I run this command, it prints out error:

```
> db.products.ensureIndex( { source_url: 1 }, { background: true, sparse: true, unique: true } )
{
    "createdCollectionAutomatically" : false,
    "numIndexesBefore" : 4,
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "E11000 duplicate key error index: snapyshop_production.products.$source_url_1  dup key: { : null }",
    "code" : 11000
}
```

I really have no idea how to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sparse index you're creating will allow multiple documents to exist without a `source_url` field, but will still only allow one document where the field is present with a value of `null`.  In other words, the sparse index doesn't treat the `null` value case any different, only the missing field case.

So the typical way to handle your problem would be to update your collection to remove the `source_url` field from your existing docs where its value is `null` before creating the index:

```js
db.products.update({source_url: null}, {$unset: {source_url: true}}, {multi: true})
```

And then use the absence of the field as your `null` indicator in your program logic.

Answer (score 0):

I found that just searching for documents with a null value returned many more documents than searching for documents where the field exists and the field is null returned a much smaller result set.  Just searching for null includes the null values and the unset ones.  I think I can improve slightly on the accepted answer with this:

```
db.products.updateMany({$and:[{source_url: null}, {source_url: {$exists: true}}]}, {$unset: {source_url: true}})
```